# How create .git directory in git directory parent

Tags: git, ansible, gitlab, ansible-galaxy

I would like to use ansible-galaxy with my own role and own repo.

I need to call each role separately

I want to create a parent folder named roles and subdirectory with role httpd - mysql etc

Each role must be cloned without other roles

src : `git@gitlab.com:ansible/roles/httpd.git`

Can I do that with gitlab? when I create a new project it automatically
creates .git.

Thanx for the help.

Comment: I think you want [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) but TBH, this question is not clear at all.

Comment: Yes but with submodule you must always clone the parent folder. Yes you're rigth my question is not very clear, i will update it